# Data import in solr from multiple entities

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler, data-import

Currently i have a Solr core, which is importing data from multiple entities, i.e 2 different MySQL tables.

I have to import data in the same core through 3rd entity which is another core in the same Solr Database.
I found a documentation on many different sites which were guiding how to import data from multiple entities which is mostly MySQL dbs.

But I want to modify solr `data-config.xml` to import data from all the three entities simultaneously. Needing pointers for my queries.

Comment: So your data-config.xml would be same for all three sources, except the connection parameters?

Comment: yes cheffe, all the three entities should be in `data-config.xml` file. But I am sure how to import data from another solr core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got a solution.

We need to modify `data-config.xml` file, under which there would be 3 different entities. 2 from MySQL and 1 from Solr core itself.

For MySQL, entity should be something like this

```
<entity name="entity name"
    dataSource="data source created in the file"
    query="SQL query to retrieve the data"
    >
```

For Solr, entity should be something like this

```
<entity name="entity name"
    processor="SolrEntityProcessor"
    query="*:*"
    url="url for solr db or particular core"
    />
```